# Append a line to file then remove it shortly after

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to append a line to a file and then send it (with `discord.py`). I don't want the original file to be saved with the new line so I'd either want to remove the line that gets added right after or just don't change the original file at all.

I can't seem to figure out how to remove  it, this is the code (it does not remove the last line).

````
if command == "beta":
   betawrite = open("otbeta.txt", "a")
   betawrite.write(str(message.author.id))
   betawrite.close()
   with open("otbeta.txt", 'rb') as betaOT:
      await message.author.send("File.")
      await message.author.send(file=discord.File(betaOT, 'beta.cfg'))
   await message.delete()```
````

Comment: It might be easier to copy the file, add the line, send the copy and then delete the copy.

Comment: How'd I do that?

Comment: You'd need to use some python utilities - [shutil](https://www.guru99.com/python-copy-file.html) is probably worth investigating. What is your OS?

Comment: I'm using win10

Comment: I see they are text files. Check if *discord.File* supports *file like* objects (iterators), you can solve without writing to disk.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere is he another user pretending a full solution in 5 minutes ? Sometimes I feel annoyed to help...

Comment: @Massimo - agreed, don't know what else to say about that.